# snails on a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, convergence-divergence

suppose you have $4$ snails arranged on the surface of an equilateral tetrahedron(all sides equal, each snail is numbered from $1$ to $4$, and that the snail numbered $1$ moves toward snail numbered $2$,$2$ moves toward snail numbered $3$,$3$ moves toward snail numbered $4$,$4$ moves toward snail numbered $1$.

so my question is will they converge? Where will they converge? Will it be at the center?

Comment: What is the "center" of the surface of a tetrahedron?

Comment: i think it is where the centroid of all the four faces join.

Comment: You are picturing a *solid* tetrahedron, methinks.  The *surface* doesn't have a center.

Comment: maybe not, my actual question is if and where they will converge?

Comment: might i also add, they are free to move in any 3-d space, aren't constrained.

Comment: If they do converge, it has to be the center, assuming they all move at the same speed, just by using a symmetry argument.

Comment: They will spiral inwards, meeting in finite time and by symmetry this will be at the centre.  They will be spinning infinitely fast at the end.

Comment: @Henry Well, symmetry by itself doesn't give you that they will spiral into the center.

Comment: @Henry You are also assuming some kind of gravitational acceleration, which OP hasn't talked about.

Comment: @user3217013: I have slightly adjusted my comment.  But their speed is presumably constant, so their distance apart reduces at a constant rate, and the only acceleration is involved in turning to stay pointed at their respective targets.

Comment: it would be nice to have a mathematical description.

Comment: If the snail is allowed to move in 3d-space into the inside of tetrahedron, it will definitely converge to the centroid in finite time. If the snail is constrained to move only on the surface, then judging from the corresponding result on the unit sphere. The trajectories of the snails will most likely converge to a square obtained by joining the 4 midpoints between the initial positions of snail pairs $1/2$, $2/3$, $3/4$ and $4/1$.

Comment: @Derg What do you mean?